Is it possible to replace a HttpMessageHandler?
A library i use throws an exception for a not found status code in an error handler (HttpMessageHandler). This is however part of normal operation, so i would like to replace the error handler with my own so i can change this behavior (return null instead) - is this possible?

What did you try? Seems like you can just use the HttpClient constructor.

Add your own DelegatingHandler which catches the exception and returns null?

You can create a custom HttpMessageHandler that inherits DelegatingHandler and the override the sendAsync method. Here, you can check the response status and handle a 404 staus code.
Your custom handler would look something like this:
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class NotFoundHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Call the inner handler to process the request first
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        // Check if the response status code is 404 (Not Found)
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            // If 404, handle it as needed - return null, empty response, etc.
            return null; // or you could return a specific custom response if needed
        }

        return response; // Return the original response for other status codes
    }
}

Then you can pass this custom handler to a HttpClient like:
var handler = new NotFoundHandler
{
    InnerHandler = new HttpClientHandler() // or the next handler in the chain
};
var client = new HttpClient(handler);

